# How do pass arguments to a page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

I want my result to be a function, that's run in the browser context to behave like a function. So I can ask it to fetch different resources. However this `p` argument doesn't work. Why, and how do I fix it?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://hendry.iki.fi')

  const p = '/about'

  const result = await page.evaluate((p) => {
    return fetch(p)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text()
      }
    })
  })

  console.log(result)

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pass arguments to the `evaluate` method like this:

```
page.evaluate((a, b) => {
   // you can use `a` and `b` here
}, a, b);
```

You can read more on arguments for the method in the [docs here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

Comment: The docs are less clear than your concise statement for the case of multiple arguments, there are also incorrect examples elsewhere that can mislead.